# Javascript keyup html works on firefox but on chrome shows 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

Issue is that on Firefox, the following code works.  Works as in, the count is shown before text is entered and the "0/350" is replaced when text is entered.

On Chrome, the 0/350 appears, but then when text is entered, the 0/350 stays but a new 1/350 appears next to it.  So ultimately, there is one blank 0/350 and one next to it, counting as it should.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= form.label :description, class: "form-label"  %>
   <%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control message" %>
   <span class="countdown float-right">0/350</span>
</div>

<script>
  $(".message").on("keyup", function () {
           var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength")
           var remaining = $(this).val().length
           $(this).next().text(remaining + '/' + maxLength)
   })
</script>
```

**Now if I use:**

```
<span class="countdown float-right"></span>
```

Note, there is no "0/350", it will work on both browsers, but it won't appear until text is entered.  There is no CSS involved as well.

How can I make it so the count is appeared on Chrome as well for all browsers like how it works on Firefox?

Comment: what is `".message"` - surely you could create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example and make it a runnable snippet

Comment: Added the entire form text field code @JaromandaX

Comment: oh, right, so `<%=` is some preprocessor stuff that means nothing ... any chance of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to your problem is quite easy, just call it a function after the page loaded.

```
    function getcountonstart(){
               var maxLength = $(".message").attr("maxlength")
               var remaining = $(".message").val().length
               $(".message").next().text(remaining + '/' + maxLength)
       }
       //Call the function
       getcountonstart();
```

EDIT: FULL CODE OF THE SCRIPT!

```
 <script>
  $(".message").on("keyup", function () {
           var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength")
           var remaining = $(this).val().length
           $(this).next().text(remaining + '/' + maxLength)
   })
   function getcountonstart(){
        var maxLength = $(".message").attr("maxlength")
        var remaining = $(".message").val().length
        $(".message").next().text(remaining + '/' + maxLength)
   }
   getcountonstart();
</script>
```

Comment: Hm, that works in displaaying but doesn't update counter in real time.

Comment: You know just add it next to the keyup method of your's, this will get the starting length of your input box. And I already tested in firefox.

Comment: Oddly, even when removing "0/350" it still appears in production and the same thing happens where two are visible once the typing begins.  I have turbolinks for rails.  I removed it from the layout but still working that way